# How do I check migratable target status with weblogic scripting tool (wlst)?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have configured a weblogic cluster that consists of two servers configured as migratable targets. This way I can use `wlst` to migrate the services that run in one of the servers to the other with the command `migrate('serverX', 'serverX').

But before run `migrate` command I'd like to check if each migratable target is running in its preferred server so I run `migrate` only if needed.

Does anyone know how to check it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this with wlst, here are some steps:

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic','http://myserver:7701')
cd('MigratableTargets')
ls() #this will list out all migratable objects
cd('<migratable name>')
ls('UserPreferredServer')
ls('HostingServer')
```

That will list your preferred server and the currently hosted server. You can use the current management object `cmo` and check to see if they are equal:

```
cd('<migratable name>')
if(cmo.getUserPreferredServer() == cmo.getHostingServer())
   ...
   migrate('serverX', 'servery')
```

You can see some of the calls that are available in the [Oracle Weblogic API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/index-files/index-7.html).